# StackOverflowError using this.draw()

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-custom-view

I am trying to display a bitmap on a canvas (or create a canvas *from* a bitmap, as these seem to be two different things?). Thanks to some very helpful advice I got here yesterday, the best approach to this seemed to be to create my own custom View first, then implement all the functionality I need within that. It was suggested I do not need to extend surfaceView for this, as I only require very simple functionality, such as pan/pinch-zoom/clicking the image, so I am extending View.

The problem with this code is that, even before I run it, when I click on the Graphical Layout of this view in Eclipse, I get a StackOverflowError. I can only assume this is because the line `this.draw(canvas);` is being called recursively or something. When I comment that line out, and uncomment the line above it, `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);`, the image displays perfectly in the Graphical Layout, but when I run the app, I get Force Close.

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.testmapbmp);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
} 

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas); 
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
    this.draw(canvas); 
    //canvas.save();
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening? Here is a link to the question I posted before too, in case it helps shed some light on what I am trying to achieve: [Displaying a Bitmap on Canvas in Surfaceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616724/displaying-a-bitmap-on-canvas-in-surfaceview)

Any and all suggestions much appreciated!!

Comment: can u post logcat error?

Comment: Seems to me that when you call this.draw(), the onDraw() gets called back, so you enter an infinite loop.

Comment: 03-26 13:36:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-26 13:36:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.conor.gmitpin/com.conor.gmitpin.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.conor.gmitpin.CanvasView

03-26 13:36:45.678: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: Sorry! That's the logcat output but it appeared a bit messy there! It's way longer than that, that's just the first error it gets..

Comment: logicalfox, when you have more information to add, you can edit the question instead of adding it in the comments. This will allow you to use the full slate of markdown formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.draw(canvas)` calls the `onDraw()`.

Comment: Oh ok! yeah I immediately see why that would be a problem! Can you suggest where to move that line of code to then? Thanks

Comment: You have to remove it. You do not have to call it directly. You should draw on the canvas the onDraw is providing you

Answer (score 0):

This code will endup doing a recursive call to onDraw(), and hence causing the stack memory to be eaten up.